# TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize) WebSocket DISCONNECT /public_chat/1/ [127.0.0.1:50083]

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, channel

I am following `Coding With Mitch` chat app and I am stuck on an Error.

When I run server, it is working fine but when I refresh the browser then it is showing

> TypeError: object.**init**() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
> WebSocket DISCONNECT /public_chat/1/ [127.0.0.1:50083]

settings.py

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

routing.py

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.urls import path, re_path

from chat.consumers import ChatConsumer
from public_chat.consumers import PublicChatConsumer
from notification.consumers import NotificationConsumer


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter([
                    re_path('', NotificationConsumer.as_asgi()),
                    re_path('chat/<room_id>/', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
                    re_path('public_chat/<room_id>/', PublicChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
            ])
        )
    ),
})
```

`websockets.py`

```
import json

from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

from ..consumer import AsyncConsumer, SyncConsumer
from ..exceptions import (
    AcceptConnection,
    DenyConnection,
    InvalidChannelLayerError,
    StopConsumer,
)


class WebsocketConsumer(SyncConsumer):

groups = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if self.groups is None:
            self.groups = []

    def websocket_connect(self, message):

        try:
            for group in self.groups:
                async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(group, 
self.channel_name)
        except AttributeError:
            raise InvalidChannelLayerError(
                "BACKEND is unconfigured or doesn't support groups"
            )
            try:
            self.connect()
        except AcceptConnection:
            self.accept()
        except DenyConnection:
            self.close()

    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def accept(self, subprotocol=None):

    super().send({"type": "websocket.accept", "subprotocol": subprotocol})

    def websocket_receive(self, message):

        if "text" in message:
            self.receive(text_data=message["text"])
        else:
            self.receive(bytes_data=message["bytes"])

        def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
  
        pass

    def send(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None, close=False):

        if text_data is not None:
            super().send({"type": "websocket.send", "text": text_data})
        elif bytes_data is not None:
            super().send({"type": "websocket.send", "bytes": bytes_data})
        else:
            raise ValueError("You must pass one of bytes_data or text_data")
        if close:
            self.close(close)

    def close(self, code=None):

        if code is not None and code is not True:
            super().send({"type": "websocket.close", "code": code})
        else:
            super().send({"type": "websocket.close"})

    def websocket_disconnect(self, message):

        try:
            for group in self.groups:
                async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
                    group, self.channel_name
                )
        except AttributeError:
            raise InvalidChannelLayerError(
                "BACKEND is unconfigured or doesn't support groups"
            )
        self.disconnect(message["code"])
        raise StopConsumer()

    def disconnect(self, code):

        pass


class JsonWebsocketConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):


    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None, **kwargs):
         if text_data:
            self.receive_json(self.decode_json(text_data), **kwargs)
        else:
            raise ValueError("No text section for incoming WebSocket frame!")

     def receive_json(self, content, **kwargs):
 
        pass

    def send_json(self, content, close=False):
 
        super().send(text_data=self.encode_json(content), close=close)

    @classmethod
    def decode_json(cls, text_data):
        return json.loads(text_data)

    @classmethod
    def encode_json(cls, content):
        return json.dumps(content)


class AsyncWebsocketConsumer(AsyncConsumer):


    groups = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self,*args, **kwargs)
        if self.groups is None:
            self.groups = []

    async def websocket_connect(self, message):
 
      try:
            for group in self.groups:
                await self.channel_layer.group_add(group, self.channel_name)
        except AttributeError:
            raise InvalidChannelLayerError(
                "BACKEND is unconfigured or doesn't support groups"
            )
        try:
            await self.connect()
        except AcceptConnection:
            await self.accept()
        except DenyConnection:
            await self.close()

    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

    async def accept(self, subprotocol=None):
 
        await super().send({"type": "websocket.accept", "subprotocol": subprotocol})

    async def websocket_receive(self, message):
 
       if "text" in message:
            await self.receive(text_data=message["text"])
        else:
            await self.receive(bytes_data=message["bytes"])

    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
  
        pass

    async def send(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None, close=False):

        if text_data is not None:
            await super().send({"type": "websocket.send", "text": text_data})
        elif bytes_data is not None:
            await super().send({"type": "websocket.send", "bytes": bytes_data})
        else:
            raise ValueError("You must pass one of bytes_data or text_data")
        if close:
            await self.close(close)

    async def close(self, code=None):
   
       if code is not None and code is not True:
            await super().send({"type": "websocket.close", "code": code})
        else:
            await super().send({"type": "websocket.close"})

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, message):

        try:
            for group in self.groups:
                await self.channel_layer.group_discard(group, self.channel_name)
         except AttributeError:
            raise InvalidChannelLayerError(
                "BACKEND is unconfigured or doesn't support groups"
            )
        await self.disconnect(message["code"])
        raise StopConsumer()

    async def disconnect(self, code):

        pass


class AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):


    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None, **kwargs):
        if text_data:
            await self.receive_json(await self.decode_json(text_data), **kwargs)
        else:
            raise ValueError("No text section for incoming WebSocket frame!")

    async def receive_json(self, content, **kwargs):

        pass

    async def send_json(self, content, close=False):
    """
    Encode the given content as JSON and send it to the client.
    """
    await super().send(text_data=await self.encode_json(content), close=close)

@classmethod
async def decode_json(cls, text_data):
    return json.loads(text_data)

@classmethod
async def encode_json(cls, content):
    return json.dumps(content)
```

`settings.py`:

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'brain.routing.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

**When i try to inspect the browser page then i got one error**

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You in Advance

Comment: Yes, BUT i haven't build custom websockets . It's in channels package. I've deleted the websockets.py from the question. Because it is just showing in the Terminal. 
See the screenshot in the Question

Comment: Please don't post errors as screenshots. You can and should copy-paste from the terminal.

Comment: @AKX, i will upload

Comment: Welcome to SO @developer ! It may help too if you could somehow produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @AjayLingayat, I uploaded BUT i think it's the default downloaded with channels.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this myself. Turns out with Channels 3.x, "Consumers now have an `as_asgi()` class method you need to call when setting up your routing"

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releases/3.0.0.html#update-to-asgi-3

Comment: Now it is saying.`ValueError("No route found for path %r." % path)
ValueError: No route found for path 'public_chat/1/'.
WebSocket DISCONNECT /public_chat/1/ [127.0.0.1:58739]`. I have Updated my question ( Uploaded my routing.py )

Comment: You might need path instead of re_path

Comment: I changed it, Now i got 1channels.exceptions.InvalidChannelLayerError: Cannot import BACKEND 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer' specified for default1. Updated question ( added settings.py )

Answer (score 2):

Just install this version

```
pip install channels==2.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see the code that instantiates a `AsyncWebsocketConsumer` to confirm, but it looks like it is being instantiated with some arguments.

The base class, `AsyncConsumer` does not accept additional arguments in `__init()__`, in fact it doesn't even implement `__init__()`. Instead it defaults to `object.__init__()` which is why the traceback mentions `object.__init()__`.

Given that the base classes do not accept any construction arguments you do not need to pass anything to their `__init__()` methods.

So, don't create `AsyncWebsocketConsumer` with arguments and the problem should go away.

Comment: But, what should i remove ?

Comment: When i remove the super(). full line. It is giving me  TypeError: PublicChatConsumer() takes no arguments
WebSocket DISCONNECT /public_chat/1/ [127.0.0.1:51881]

Comment: That sounds like an unrelated issue that is probably now exposed because this particular problem is fixed. Post the code that creates the `AsyncWebsocketConsumer` object.

Comment: I am uploading full websocets.py file

Comment: I have uploaded

Comment: New code still does not show instantiation of `AsyncWebsocketConsumer`. Try adding some `print()` statements to your `__init__()` method. `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
 print(f'{args = }, {kwargs = }')` Then we can see if there is anything important being passed to it. Also show where any `AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer` objects are created since this is a child class of  `AsyncWebsocketConsumer`.

Comment: Regarding the `PublicChatConsumer()` error, there is no mention of that class in any code that you've shown.

Comment: @developer: I'm asking you to show how those objects are created in _Python_. The client javascript code is irrelevant at this point. If you make the changes that I suggest (removing the `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` call) then the problem that is the subject of your question will go away. The next problem with `PublicChatConsumer` looks to be similar. Ask a new question about that if you can't solve it yourself.